# More concise way of writing a loop inside a loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of objects that are a specific class within my code like so,

```
[object1, object2, object3, object4, object5, object6]
```

Namely this class has two attributes: `class.score` and `class.id`

I might have objects with the same id. Eg.:

```
[object1.id, object2.id, object3.id, object4.id, object5.id, object6.id] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]
```

But with different scores. Eg.:

```
[object1.score, object2.score, object3.score, object4.score, object5.score,
object6.score] = [0.25, 0.55, 0.6, 0.4, 0.30, .33]
```

What I want to do is to have list with no duplicates of this objects id-wise but
adding the scores. So for the previous example the output would be:

```
[object1.id, object2.id, object3.id, object4.id] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
[object1.score, object2.score, object3.score, object4.score] = [.25, .85, .93, .4]
```

I have managed to do that with two for loops:

```
k = 1
    for object in list_of_objects:
        j = 1
        for object2 in list_of_objects:
            if object.id == object2.id and j > k:
                object.score = object.score + object2.score
                list_of_objects.remove(object2)
            j += 1
        k += 1
```

But I'm looking to do it in a more python-ish, way something along the lines of:

```
newlist[:] = [ x for x in list_of_objects if certain_condition(x)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you care about the order the final list is in?

Comment: how can two same objects have different attributes?

Comment: @RenaeLider, I don't think it's there Python `id()`, it's just an attribute called `id`. I don't think the repeats in that first list are intended to mean it's the same object (though certainly it does imply that on its own).

Comment: @Cyphase not really, I'm more concerned about keeping just a unique id with the correct sum of scores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do this using a dictionary to detect already seen objects:

```
seen = {}
for x in my_objects:
    if x.id in seen:
        seen[x.id].score += x.score
    else:
        seen[x.id] = x
my_objects[:] = seen.values()
```

Using a dictionary makes the computation `O(n)` instead of `O(n²)`

Comment: @RenaeLider: a set of what? If you keep just the `.id` once you see it's an already seen object you also need to find the original to add the score to it

Comment: do I get to keep the class structure by doing 
`my_objects[:] = list(seen.values())` ?

Comment: @DiegoAgher: yes, `seen.values()` are the original objects to which the `score` field has been incremented. The `list()` call is not needed if assigning back to the original list (I edited the post removing it).

Answer (score 6):

`itertools.groupby` was made exactly for this situation
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby
# object.id is our key:
keyfunc = lambda obj: obj.id
list_of_objects = sorted(list_of_objects, key=keyfunc)

scores = [sum(score_list) for id, score_list in groupby(list_of_objects, keyfunc)]
ids = [id for id, score_list in groupby(list_of_objects, keyfunc)]
```

Comment: but I want to alter the list of objects not create a new list @frank

Answer (score 1):

You can go using the [Python Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), within a single line, by supplying an additional custom function:

```
def r(l, o):
    if len(l) > 0 and l[-1].id == o.id:
        l[-1].score += o.score
    else:
        l.append(o)
    return l

key = attrgetter('id')
```

And then simply use the [**`reduce`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function in combination with [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and the above custom function:

```
list_of_objects = reduce(r, sorted(list_of_objects, key=key), [])
```

Then you will have what you need:

```
[1: 0.25, 2: 0.85, 3: 0.93, 4: 0.4]
```